# AS2 - Make Object Faster

Tags: actionscript-2

I wanted to make an object faster in AS2. Currently this is my code:

.frameRate doesn't help make the object go faster. Is there any other way?

Comment: There is something missing here ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in [shift].